# svg+xml on Apache still being served as text/plain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, svg

I *think* I've covered all the bases, but my SVG is still coming over as text.

Here's the SVG code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="285px" height="382px" version="1.1"><defs/><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)"><ellipse cx="142" cy="135" rx="110" ry="95" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" transform="rotate(26,142,135)" pointer-events="none"/><ellipse cx="142" cy="135" rx="106" ry="91" fill="transparent" stroke="#000000" transform="rotate(26,142,135)" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 12 270 L 142 270 L 162 290 L 162 380 L 32 380 L 12 360 L 12 270 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 32 380 L 32 290 L 12 270 M 32 290 L 162 290" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/></g></svg>
```

My .htaccess file has this:

```
# SVG
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddType image/svg+xml .svgz
AddEncoding gzip .svg
```

My httpd.conf file has this:

```
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddType image/svg+xml .svgz
```

mime.types has:

```
image/svg+xml           svg svgz
```

It will work as an embed, but not as an image tag src, or as a free-standing URL:

```
http://blogs.shu.edu/tomstest/files/2015/09/drawit-diagram.svg
```

Is there someplace else that configuration might be lurking?

---

Response Headers are as follows:

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  348
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date    Fri, 19 Feb 2016 18:58:31 GMT
Etag    "2533d2400403b62e41cfb5e995d19478"
Expires Mon, 22 Apr 2019 04:45:11 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=75
Last-Modified   Fri, 19 Feb 2016 16:41:59 GMT
Server  Apache
Vary    Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: Check response headers when you ping the image URL.

Comment: Could this be because the source file on the server doesn't have the <svg> wrapped up in an <xml> tag?